# modifying angular promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a service like this (modified for brevity (and privacy)):

```
angular.module('services', [])
.factory('obj', function ($http) {
    return {
       get: function () {
           return $http.get('/obj').then(function (response) {
               return response.data;
           });
       }
    }
});
```

It's used like this: `$scope.obj = obj.get();` to retrieve an object from the server.

I can display the object and modify MOST of it's keys, except I can't seem to modify any keys that contain arrays or other objects. I get a type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I'm trying to add to the contents of an array that exists in the promised object. I can view them, it's just that when I try and add or remove them, angular thinks it's undefined.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.then` in your controller and do the logic in the callback:

```
obj.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.obj = data;
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I'll accept when it lets me. Also, can you maybe explain what exactly is going here? I'm a n00b.

Comment: Sure, basically you are continuing the promise pattern and assigning the returned data to the `$scope` variable once the entire back-end service has been executed. For a more detailed explanation, check out: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angularjs-creating-service-with-http.html